# Configuring Web App to Serve from a Specific Base URL in IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I have an Angular app hosted within the directory structure of an IIS site,
specifically at this path:
mainSite/client/v3

Currently, to access the client app, I need to use the URL:
https://mainSite/client/v3

However,
I would like to configure the Angular app so that it runs from the base URL:
https://mainSite

How can I achieve this configuration? What steps are necessary to set it up correctly so that the Angular app is accessible from the desired base URL

Comment: In IIS there are [virtual directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) for that purpose.

Comment: Please learn IIS URL Rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [url rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to redirect https://mainSite/client/v3 to https://mainSite, this demo you can use as a reference:

```
 <rewrite>
   <rules>  
     <rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="client/v3" />            
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://mainSite" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```